# XSLT - Uncomment the element based on tile content

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML

```
<section counter="no" type="index">
<title><target id="page417"/>Index</title>
<para>Page numbers in italics represent applications. Page numbers followed by <emph type="italic">f</emph> and <emph type="italic">t</emph> indicate figures and tables, respectively.</para>
<section counter="no">
<title>A</title>
....................
<litem><para>Ammonia/ammonium ion (NH<sub>3</sub>/<!--<inline-figure xlink:href="images/9781604063172_in108.jpg"/>-->)</para>
.....................
</section>
</section>
```

Output should be,

```
<section counter="no" type="index">
<title><target id="page417"/>Index</title>
<para>Page numbers in italics represent applications. Page numbers followed by <emph type="italic">f</emph> and <emph type="italic">t</emph> indicate figures and tables, respectively.</para>
<section counter="no">
<title>A</title>
....................
<litem><para>Ammonia/ammonium ion (NH<sub>3</sub>/<inline-figure xlink:href="images/9781604063172_in108.jpg"/>)</para>
.....................
</section>
```

My xslt is like as,

```
<xsl:template match="section[@type='index']">
    <xsl:if test="contains(.,comment())">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

We need to remove comment based on title content. While using above xslt, all content extracted from nodes. Only value is available in output. Could you please guide us.

Comment: _We need to remove comment based on `title` content_ - Can you share the requirement here? You would also need `identity template` to copy everything and retain it in output. This will ensure all nodes are available in output.

Comment: Yes..I want to remove the comment based on title. Whenever title is "index" and comments are appear within that specified section then we need to remove uncomment it.

Comment: In this condition, we need to comment entire "Index" section part. Earlier, we have used this xslt to comment entire section part.

Comment: <xsl:template match="section[@type='index']">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="contains(title, 'Index')">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/></xsl:copy>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>            
    </xsl:template>

Comment: While using above xslt, we are getting validation error. Bcoz, comment is appearing within comment so we planned to uncomment the comment nodes then comment the entire section. Could you please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem "uncomment the element" suggests that you aren't thinking in terms of the actual data model here. There is no element to be uncommented: there is a comment containing text which contains XML markup which can be parsed to create an element.

The best way to handle this is to extract the text of the comment and submit it to an XML parser. In XSLT 3.0 you can do this by calling the parse-xml() or parse-xml-fragment() functions. In earlier versions you will need to use an extension function (which might be available from your vendor, or you could write it yourself.

disable-output-escaping can solve the problem in some cases but it's a crude tool because (a) it only works in certain situations, and (b) you can't do much manipulation of the content before outputting it.